# Unhandled exception - Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have three classes an one function that runs fine on certain place in the code and crashes if I put it on other place and I can't figure it out, why it happens. I will be happy fore guidance.

```
class BaseClass
{
    friend class B;

protected:
    string m_name;

    BaseClass::BaseClass();                 // implementation doesn't matter
    virtual bool execute  (SRV *p_Srv) = 0;
    virtual void setName(string name)
    {
      m_name = name;
    }
    ~BaseClass(void);               // implementation doesn't matter
};


class derivedClass:public BaseClass
{
    friend class B;

protected:
    derivedClass(void);                 // implementation doesn't matter
    bool execute (SRV *p_Srv);          // implementation doesn't matter
    ~derivedClass(void);                // implementation doesn't matter
};


class B
{
    BaseClasse **array;
    string twoDimArray[2][MAX_PARAMS_SIZE];

    bool function()
    {
     ....
     p_pipeline[i] = new derivedClass(twoDimArray);
     ** EDIT: array[i]->setName("name"); **             <------ problematic line
     p_pipeline[i]->setName("name");                  <------ problematic line
     if (checkIfNewFilterCreated(i, "name") == "-1")                                                    
        throw msg;
     ....
    }

 string B::checkIfNewFilterCreated(int index, string name)
 {
     if (p_pipeline[index] = NULL)
         return "-1";
     else
     {
         m_numOfFiltersCreated++ ;
         return name;   
     }
 }
}
```

The code runs fine with this sequence of command, but if I change the 'problematic line' to other place:

```
     ....
     p_pipeline[i] = new derivedClass(twoDimArray);
     ** EDIT: array[i] = new derivedClass(twoDimArray); **
     if (checkIfNewFilterCreated(i, "name") == "-1")                                                    
        throw msg;
     p_pipeline[i]->setName("name");                <------ problematic line
     ** EDIT: array[i]->setName("name"); **                <------ problematic line
     ....
```

, I get:

> Access violation reading location 0x00000000

I am sorry if the code too long, I struggle with it for a long time...

Thanks.

Comment: Use vectors and smart pointers and I bet your problems will disappear.. `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClasse>>> aray;` Well worth the effort to learn what that means and how to use it.

Comment: I think the error might be somewhere in `checkIfNewFilterCreated()`, can you post some code?

Comment: And where is the `p_pipeline` definition?

Comment: The destructor of BaseClass is not virtual, and that's the only big problem I see in your code. Other problems are hidden in the code you did not post.

Comment: `p_pipeline[i]->setName("name");` you have a null pointer somewhere.

Comment: Maybe `checkIfNewFilterCreated(i, "name")` Could that be trashing the array instead of checking. Do you have `if (p_pipeline[i] = NULL) {` in checkIfNewFilterCreated when you meant this `if (p_pipeline[i] == NULL) {`

Comment: Where exactly do you have a constructor that can make `new derivedClass(twoDimArray)` compile and work correctly?

Comment: Im sorry :\ I wrote if (p_pipeline[i] = NULL) instead of ==. thank you  drescherjm!!

Comment: My advice about this is to always pay careful attention to your compiler warnings. Any descent compiler should have warned you of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assignment in this line:

`if (p_pipeline[index] = NULL)`

instead of comparisson

`if (p_pipeline[index] == NULL)`

That's why you are accessing address `0x00000000`

Comment: I wish compilers would promote this from a warning to an error, it's far too easy to do.